# Need a jquery rating slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can anyone suggest a good jquery rating slider. My main use is i need a rating slider to get ratings between 1 to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the main jquery slider.  It turns an element into a slider with a simple:

```
  $("#slider").slider();
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider